# System of nondistinct representatives efficiently solvable?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

We have sets *S*<sub>1</sub>, *S*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *S<sub>n</sub>*. These sets do not have to be disjoint. Our task is to select a representative member for each set, such that the total number of elements selected is as small as possible. One element may be present in more than one set, and can represent all the sets it is included in. Is there an algorithm to solve this efficiently?

Comment: Can you define a representative member ? If one element is common to all sets is it the representative of all sets and the answer is that element?

Comment: It seems that what you seek is the [union-find algorithm](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Union_Find). If this is the case, I'll post a detailed answer.

Comment: @rrufai, not necessarily. For example `S1={1,2},S2={2,3},S3={3,4}`. The answer to his question is 2, i.e. `2` and `3` can be chosen as representatives of the three sets and that is the smallest number. How would you solve this with disjoint sets? Would you union `S1` and `S2` because they share a number? Then you would union `S2` and `S3`, too, but that leaves you with one final set.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Yes, you're right. It won't work. Let S.e represent some element of S. You could union all possible combinations -- union(S1.e, S2.e), union(S1.e, S3.e), union(S2.e, S3.e) -- all n(n-1)/2 of them, but union is destructive. The base sets are constantly changing as you invoke union.

Answer (score 8):

It is easier to answer this question after restatement: let the original sets *S*<sub>1</sub>, *S*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *S<sub>n</sub>* be elements of the universe and let the original set members be sets themselves: *T*<sub>1</sub>, *T*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *T<sub>m</sub>* (where *T*<sub>i</sub> contains elements {*S*<sub>j</sub>} which are the original sets containing corresponding member).

Now we have to cover universe *S*<sub>1</sub>, *S*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *S<sub>n</sub>* with sets *T*<sub>1</sub>, *T*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *T<sub>m</sub>*. Which is exactly [Set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). It is a well known NP-hard problem, so there is no algorithm to solve it efficiently (unless P=NP, as theorists usually say). As you can see from Wikipedia page, there is a greedy approximation algorithm; it is efficient, but approximation ratio is not very good.

Comment: Yes, set cover is NP-hard. But reducing an arbitrary problem to an NP-hard problem does not make the original problem NP-hard.

Comment: @sentinel: That's true. But in this particular case there is no reduction to NP-hard problem. Instead we have a restatement or, in other words, identity to NP-hard problem.

Comment: I had to read it carefully, because I was eager to not agree that there wasn't an efficient algorithm for this problem, but Evgeny's answer seems clearly the right answer. You could improve your answer, showing how to reduce set cover to this problem, it would prove that this problem is NP-hard.

Comment: The question doesn't seem like he needs to cover `{S1,...,Sn}`, but rather identify the smallest set of elements that are present each in at least one and overall in all sets. For example if `S1={1,2}` and `S2={2,3,4,5}`, then element 2 is representative for both sets, so the minimum number of representatives is 1. This is different from the set cover problem.

Comment: @Shahbaz Evgeny is saying let U={S1,S2} be your universe and define T1={S1}, T2={S1,S2}, T3=T4=T5={S2} (each Ti being the set of all sets that contains i). We can cover the universe with T2, which corresponds to the fact that {2} is the minimum hitting set.

Comment: @jerry, I see. I didn't understand that from the text of the answer

Comment: @sentinel if Evgeny has answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, Mark Leighton Fisher has some good suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Not to steal Evgeny's glory, but here's a rather straightforward way of showing perhaps more rigorously that the general case of the poster's problem is NP-hard.

Consider the [minimum vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover_problem) problem of finding a minimum set *X* from vertices *V* in an [simple graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29#Simple_graph) (*V*,*E*) where every edge in E is adjacent to at least one vertex in *X*.

An edge can be represented by an unordered two-element set {*v<sub>a</sub>*, *v<sub>b</sub>*} where *v<sub>a</sub>* and *v<sub>b</sub>* are distinct elements in *V*. Note that an edge *e* represented as {*v<sub>a</sub>*, *v<sub>b</sub>*} is adjacent to *v<sub>c</sub>* if and only if *v<sub>c</sub>* is an element of {*v<sub>a</sub>*, *v<sub>b</sub>*}.

Hence, the minimal vertex cover problem is the same as finding a minimum size subset *X* of *V* where each edge set {*v<sub>a</sub>*, *v<sub>b</sub>*} defined by an edge in *E* contains an element that is in *X*.

If one has an algorithm to efficiently solve the original stated problem, then one has an algorithm to efficiently solve the above problem, and therefore one can solve the minimal vertex cover problem efficiently as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that by "efficiently," you mean in polynomial time.

Evgeny Kluev is correct, the problem is NP-hard. The decision version of it is known as the [hitting set problem](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hitting%20set%20problem) and was shown to be what we now call NP-complete soon after the introduction of that concept. While it's true that Evgeny's reduction is from the hitting set problem to the set cover problem, it's not hard to see an explicit inverse reduction.

Given a set C={C<sub>1</sub>,C<sub>2</sub>,...C<sub>m</sub>} whose union is U={u<sub>1</sub>,u<sub>2</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub>}, we want to find a minimal-cardinality subset C' whose union is also equal to U. Define S<sub>i</sub> in your initial problem as {C<sub>j</sub> in C | u<sub>i</sub> is an element of C<sub>j</sub>}. The minimum hitting set of S={S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,...,S<sub>n</sub>} is then equal to our desired C'.

Comment: what you've described is not the hitting set problem. In the hitting set problem, your set C' is only required to have one element from each Cj. So, the union of Cj is not necessarily equal to U.

Comment: @rrufai The C' we're looking for is a solution to (the optimization form of) the **set covering problem on C**. Therefore, the union of C' must be equal to the union of C (which I've called U). By defining S appropriately (which can be done in polynomial time), a solution to (the optimization form of) the **hitting set problem on S** yields a solution to our **set covering problem on C**. If we have a polynomial time algorithm that always solves the hitting set problem, NP must be equal to P since the set covering problem is NP-hard.

Comment: I don't understand what you just said. I do agree that the SO's problem is the hitting set problem, but I can't see why u'll need to invoke set cover at all. Does that needlessly complicates this discussion?

Comment: @rrufai The original question asked if there's an efficient algorithm to solve the problem. The answer is probably not (and certainly not one that is already well known) because the problem is "difficult" (called NP-hard). We know this because we can show that a second problem that has been proved to be "difficult" becomes "easy" if you know how to solve the first problem. This is what I've done with the set cover problem, which sentinel has agreed is "difficult" in a comment to Evgeny Kluev's answer.

Comment: Well, my point is that you don't need to do that since the Hitting Set problem itself has been shown to be NP complete by Karp in 1972 according to the [Wolfram link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hitting%20set%20problem) you provided.

Comment: @rrufai this discusion has become irrelevent to the stated question. If you'd really like to continue it, create a chat room and invite me.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of algorithms to look at are Simulated Annealing and Genetic Algorithms, if you can live with a solution close to optimal (they might get you the optimal solution, but not necessarily). Simulated Annealing can be made to work in production electronic CAD autoplacement (as I was part of the development team for Wintek's autoplacement program).